# XPages POI4Xpages download to network location

Tags: file-upload, download, apache-poi, xpages

Using POI4Xpages which is great [LINK](http://poi4xpages.openntf.org/)

However, I was wondering, at present, when it creates my word document, it simply downloads, like a normal download from the internet, storing it the downloads folder in windows (using Chrome anyways)

Is there a way, using POI4XPages, to instead, dump the file to a specified network location, for example a shared drive?

After that, I would simply build a link to the file using the network location, and a filename variable for example to pick the correct file.

If thats not possible, is it possible to get a handle on the file before or after it is downloaded, and then save it to a field in the xpage?

In short, I want to avoid the user downloading the file, then having to attach it manually to the xpage.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

POI allows you to get a handle to the file using the variable "workbook".  You are also able to provide the specific downloadFileName you wish to use.  Using the postGenerationProcess property you should be able to make a call to a Java method that makes the connection to your network drive where you can use the "workbook" variable and downloadFileName value to save your document.  If this doesn't work definitely post a question on their project site because the creator does reply.

Comment: Dwain's on the right path.  Via Java you should be able to get the handle on the eventual file - which is probable some kinda of Stream I assume.  Then do whatever you want with it.  You could save it to a notes doc easily enough or via more Java code save it anywhere you want.

Comment: Thanks both - I've only dipped my toe into Java, so looks like I'm going to have to dive in now!

Comment: Go watch some awesome videos on NotesIn9